# Why does Java just skip the loops in this code?

Tags: java, loops

I provided a code snippet below.

`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    int[][] matrix = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};


    System.out.println(hasSymmetry(matrix)); // returns true, so the isComputable condition is verified and the code not executed. Otherwise, it would return false. 
   

}


public static boolean hasSymmetry(int[][] matrix){
    
    // isComputable is defined somewhere else, and it works as expected. 

    if(!isComputable(matrix)){    
        return false;
    }
    

    int length = matrix.length;

    // the loops are skipped without any error. I added the print statements for checking, but they simply don't happen. 

    for (int i = 0; i == length; i++){
        System.out.println("Inside loop" + i);
        for (int j = 0; j == length; j++){
            if (matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i]) {
                System.out.println(matrix[i][j] + " vs " + matrix[j][i]);
                return false;
            }                
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}
`

Anyone has an idea why the loops are skipped?

- I tried making the conditions inside the loop to be i - 2 and j - 2, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The `for` keeps running as long as the condition is *true*, but yours (`i==length`) is false immediately.

Comment: yeah...pretty sure you want `i < length`.  Also, you might want to check to see if your incoming matrix is square.  If it isn't, your code will thrown an out of bounds exception.

Comment: Ohh, I see now! I was seeing it the other way around. Thank you! 

@CryptoFool I am checking that in "isComputable" function, but thanks for the heads up! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i == length; i++){
                  ^^
...
    for (int j = 0; j == length; j++){
                      ^^
```

There is a mistake in the termination conditions of your for loops.

Comment: That seems to have been the issue, thank you! :)